# Checking an integer then returning a string

Tags: c#, validation, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

So I have a small snippet of code that I may use when I want to quickly check an integer before deciding what a string value will be:

```
string status = (statusID == 0 ? "Inactive" : "Active");
```

However, I cannot remember what this practice / piece of code is called of referred to as. I wanted to implement a similar bit of code, but with two parameter checks, to check for two different numbers, giving three possible outcomes. Is this possible? Or would it be more suitable to expand this out into two usages of this code, checking for a certain string, or expand the functionality into a method?

Comment: That's a ternary operator, which is a shorthand for `if/else`, that's it. I'd say that what you're describing is a candidate for a separate, small method...

Comment: Your title is confusing, I don't see any `throw` here.

Comment: exceptions can be thrown, strings can't. You mean `return` here.

Comment: Sorry @crashmstr, like I said, I did not know what this operation was called, so my words were slightly muddled.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor, thanks! I learn something new every day :)

Comment: I'd use a `switch` statement in this case, especially if `statusID` can have more than 3 values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?:` is conditional operator in c#: [`?:` Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Just put another `?:` statement in *else* part of the first one:

```
string status = (statusID == 0 ? "Inactive" : (statusID == 1 ? "Active" : "OtherOne"));
```

That's gonna return "Inactive" for `statusID == 0`, "Active" for `statusID == 1` and "OtherOne" for others.